# Check what compiler flag is set within C++ code

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Is there a way to check what flags are set on the compiler in running C++ code?

Specifically, was this code compiled with `/fp:precise` or `/fp:fast` from within the program?

Comment: An alternative is to create your own define `/DCXXFLAGS="/O3 /fp:fast"` that you pass in via the compiler, and then you can use that as needed.  (That'd be something I'd put in the output of the `/version` flag.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the msvc documentation you can do this using predefined macros: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=msvc-160

***_M_FP_FAST Defined as 1 if the /fp:fast compiler option is set. Otherwise, undefined.***

***_M_FP_PRECISE Defined as 1 if the /fp:precise compiler option is set. Otherwise, undefined.***

Note that these are compiler specific so don't expect them to work on any other compiler.